# Are there any MTG cards which test for first strike?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Are there any Magic cards which test for first strike? I’m thinking of something like “Destroy target creature with first strike” or “Creatures with first strike get +1/+1 until end of turn”.

Comment: I removed your last sentence ("I’d also be interested in analogous questions for other keyworded abilities.") to keep the scope to one question.  Feel free to post a separate question if you want to ask something else

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Four cards specifically check for first strike:

- [Kwende, Pride of Femeref](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Kwende%2C%20Pride%20of%20Femeref) has "Creatures you control with first strike have double strike."
- [Tresserhorn Skyknight](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Tresserhorn%20Skyknight) has "Prevent all damage that would be dealt to Tresserhorn Skyknight by creatures with first strike."
- [Path of Mettle](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Path%20of%20Mettle) has

  > When Path of Mettle enters the battlefield, it deals 1 damage to each creature that doesn’t have first strike, double strike, vigilance, or haste.
  >
  > Whenever you attack with at least two creatures that have first strike, double strike, vigilance, and/or haste, transform Path of Mettle.
- [Momentum Rumbler](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Momentum%20Rumbler) has

  > Whenever Momentum Rumbler attacks, if it doesn’t have first strike, put a first strike counter on it.
  >
  > Whenever Momentum Rumbler attacks, if it has first strike, it gains double strike until end of turn.

A several cards gain or grant a variety of keyword abilities based on the abilities other creatures or creature cards have, including first strike:

- [Akroma, Vision of Ixidor](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Akroma%2C%20Vision%20of%20Ixidor)
- [Cairn Wanderer](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Cairn%20Wanderer)
- [Concerted Effort](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Concerted%20Effort)
- [Escaped Shapeshifter](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Escaped%20Shapeshifter)
- [Kathril, Aspect Warper](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Kathril%2C%20Aspect%20Warper)
- [Majestic Myriarch](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Majestic%20Myriarch)
- [Odric, Lunarch Marshal](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Odric%2C%20Lunarch%20Marshal)
- [Thunderous Orator](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Thunderous%20Orator)

Several cards exile or otherwise remove cards, and then gain a variety of keyword abilities that those cards have:

- [Animus of Predation](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Animus%20of%20Predation)
- [Death-Mask Duplicant](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Death-Mask%20Duplicant)
- [Eater of Virtue](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Eater%20of%20Virtue)
- [Rayami, First of the Fallen](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Rayami%2C%20First%20of%20the%20Fallen)
- [Soulflayer](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Soulflayer)
- [Urborg Scavengers](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Urborg%20Scavengers)

I found these using the Scryfall searches [`o:/creature.*with.*first strike/`](https://scryfall.com/search?q=o%3A%2Fcreatures.*with.*first%20strike%2F&unique=cards&as=grid&order=name), [`o:/that.*have.*first strike/`](https://scryfall.com/search?q=o%3A%2Fthat.*have.*first%20strike%2F&unique=cards&as=grid&order=name), [`o:/if.*has.*first strike/`](https://scryfall.com/search?q=o%3A%2Fif.*has.*first%20strike%2F&unique=cards&as=grid&order=name), and [`o:/as long as.*has.*first strike/`](https://scryfall.com/search?q=o%3A%2Fas%20long%20as.*has.*first%20strike%2F&unique=cards&as=grid&order=name). You could replace "first strike" with other keyword abilities in those searches to find cards that care about those keyword abilities.

Comment: Thank you for including the searches; that’s very useful information!

Answer (score 5):

Try this search: https://scryfall.com/search?q=o%3A%22with+first+strike%22

Here are two cards that meet your criteria:

- [Kwende, Pride of Femeref](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Kwende%2C%20Pride%20of%20Femeref)
- [Tresserhorn Skyknight](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Tresserhorn%20Skyknight)